# How to disallow dot character as first letter in EditText?

Tags: android

How to disallow dot character as first letter in edit text field with numberDecimal input type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to achieve this by XML setup, but this is possible using `TextWatcher` set for your `EditText`

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length() == 1 && s.charAt(0) == '.'){
            editText.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

note that `setText` line will trigger `TextWatcher` methods again, but conditions in `if` statement in `afterTextChanged` will prevent calling `setText` again

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few options here.

You could check if the value >= 1.0 (when it starts with a dot it won't be)

You could check if the first char of a string is '.'

Or implement a [regex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/)